# The test statistic in the likelihood ratio test for nested linear models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio, nested-models

Imagine that we have a family of probability disributions with p.d.f $f_{\theta}(z)$ where
$\theta \in \Theta$. We also know that there is a linear dependence between parameters. As a consequence we can restrict to a nested model with p.d.f $f_{\theta}(z)$, where $\theta \in \Theta_{0} \subseteq \Theta$.

Formally we have such a situation:
\begin{align}
\Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R}^p,~~~~ h:\mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^{p-q},~~~~  \Theta_{0} = \{\theta \in \Theta : h(\theta)=0\}.
\end{align}
where h is a linear map onto $\mathbb{R}^{p-q}$ so we can say that:
\begin{align}
h(\theta) = A\theta  = 0,
\end{align}
where $A$ is a $(p-q) \times p$ matrix of a linear map $h$.

As a result we can say that $\Theta_{0} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^q$. HERE BEGINS MY PROBLEM.
I would be very grateful if someone could tell me why we can conclude now that 
\begin{align}
\sup \limits_{\theta \in \Theta_{1}}f_{\theta}(z) \overset{\huge{?}}{=} \sup \limits_{\theta \in \Theta}f_{\theta}(z). 
\end{align}
Consequently the test statistic of a likelihood ratio test is
\begin{align}
\lambda(z) = \frac{\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_{1}}f_{\theta}(z)}{\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_{0}}f_{\theta}(z)}\overset{\huge{?}}{=} \frac{\sup_{\theta \in \Theta}f_{\theta}(z)}{\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_{0}}f_{\theta}(z)}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusing (to me) notation in your question. If the parameter vector $\theta$ belongs to the $p$-dimensional space $\Theta$ then it is not $\theta$ again that belongs to the $q$-dimensional subspace $\Theta_0$. This is not an issue of values-taken, but of dimensions. (Also it seems that you suddenly change the parameter vector subscript from $0$ to $1$ in the $\sup$ expression).

I understand your question as follows: By assumption, part of the parameters is  a function of the rest. Denote the sub-vector containing the "dependent" elements of the $\theta$ vector as $\theta_{p-q}  \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{p-q}$, and the "independent" parameter vector as $\theta_q\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{q}$. We then have $\theta_{p-q} = g(\theta_q)$.
Then your likelihood function can be written as

$$f(z;\theta) = f(z;\theta_{p-q} , \theta_q) = f(z;g(\theta_q) , \theta_q) $$

*Given* the assumption of functional dependence among parameters, I believe you don't need to "prove" in any other way that the RHS is the same as the LHS, and so that they will have the same extrema.

The $\sup$-equality expression that you questionmark may be misleading because it could be taken to imply that it holds, *irrespective* of the existence of the functional dependence, because it does not "reveal" the functional dependence among the parameters. A more clear expression would be

$$  \sup \limits_{\{\theta_{p-q}\}\cup \{\theta_q\} =\theta \in \Theta}f(z;\theta_{p-q} , \theta_q)  \;\;\text{s.t.}\;\; \theta_{p-q} = g(\theta_q)  $$ $$=\sup \limits_{\theta_q \in \Theta_{0}}f(z;g(\theta_q) , \theta_q) $$

In other words, you just transform a maximization problem with equality constraints into an unconstrained maximization problem by inserting the constraint into the objective function.